# Pandas Pivot multiple columns into a single column

Tags: python, pandas, pivot

I have a dataset like this

```
A    B    C D
Cat Meow  1 2
Dog Grr   3 4
```

I need to convert into the bwlow format by creating new columns

```
Level Focus C D
A     Cat   1 2
A     Dog   3 4
B     Meow  1 2
B     Grr   3 4
```

I am not sure how I can achieve this using pivot_table()

Answer (score 2):

Try using `melt`:

```
df.melt(['C', 'D'], var_name='Level', value_name='Focus')
```

Output:

```
   C  D Level Focus
0  1  2     A   Cat
1  3  4     A   Dog
2  1  2     B  Meow
3  3  4     B   Grr
```

Another way for pedagogical reasons:

```
df.set_index(['C', 'D']).stack().reset_index().rename(columns={'level_2':'Level',0:'Focus'})
```

Output:

```
   C  D Level Focus
0  1  2     A   Cat
1  1  2     B  Meow
2  3  4     A   Dog
3  3  4     B   Grr
```

Answer (score 0):

Use melt and the rename columns according to your desire result.

```
df = df.melt(['C', 'D'])
df=df.rename(columns = {'variable':'Level', 'value':'Focus'}, inplace = True)
```

Comment: Check out the parameters in `melt`, `var_name` and `value_name`.  And, you cannot use `inplace=True` with reassign back to variable df.  Inplace=True returns null.

Comment: You edited your answer after viewing my answer. But I did it with different approach not like yours.